# VB.Net interface to define function returning inherited collection of type

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

Currently we're using objects and object collections like so:

```
Public Class childObj Inherits BaseObjClass Implements IInspRevChild  
  ...  
End Class  

Public Class childObj_Collection Inhertis BaseObjCollClass(Of childObj)  
  ...  
End Class  

Public Class parentObj Inherits BaseObjClass Implements IInspRev  
  ...  
  Public Function GetChildren() AS childObj_Collection Implements IInspRev.GetChildrenCollection
    ...  
  End Function  
End Class
```

I want to define an Interface with a definition for the GetChildren function.

I was going to try something like this:

```
Public Interface IInspRev  
  Function GetChildrenCollection() As BaseObjCollClass(Of BaseObjClass )  
End Interface
```

But the compiler doesn't like that. Could somebody set me straight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a circular reference problem. `BaseObjClass` implements `IInspRev`, which in turn depends on `BaseObjClass`. Compiler gets in a "chicken or egg" situation and hence fails.

A better way to define your `GetChildrenCollection` inside `IInspRev` method would likely be this:

```
Readonly Property Childrens() As ICollection(Of IInspRev)
```

If you don't need the interface to be able to add, remove or replace childs, this will be even better:

```
Readonly Property Childrens As IEnumerable(Of IInspRev)
```

Note that I made it a readonly property rather than a method. This way of exposing a collection of child objects is preferred in .NET universe.

Comment: Could I do something like this: Function GetChildrenCollection() As BaseObjCollClass(Of IInspRevChild)

Comment: @MKenyonII It would not because `BaseObjCollClass` depends on `BaseObjClass`. Use standard `ICollection` or `IEnumerable` instead.